# What is "IP-Config:" during bootup and why is it overriding my /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, dhcp

I have an `/etc/network/interfaces` file (on a 16.04 box) that looks like this:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.88.50
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.88.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.88.1
dns-domain mynet.lan
```

You'd expect this to result in `eth0` coming up with the specified IP. That is not happening. During boot, I see a line that says:

`IP-Config: eth0 hardware address e0:db:55:0c:34:7e mtu 1500 DHCP`

..and then the interface is brought up with an address ever-so-helpfully provided by the local DHCP server.

More troubling, this IP-Config line **only shows during boot** and is not visible in any of my log files.

What is IP-Config, why is it stomping on my `interfaces` file, and where can it be configured?

#### More info:

The bogus address (in my case, 192.168.88.222) is only created during boot, sometime before the `if*` scripts get to it. `ip addr` shows the wrong address (gleaned from DHCP) directly above the right address (which is marked as "secondary").

**tl;dr: Something is broadcasting for DHCP and assigning it to the NIC before they're brought up normally using the `if*` commands, leading to two addresses on the same NIC.**

If I down the interface, `ip address` shows the bogus address still associated with the NIC. If I issue an `ip address flush eth0`, the bogus address is removed, and does not come back on a subsequent interface restart - but it **does** come back when the system is rebooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found what was causing this. Not by finding a hidden pointer to it somewhere, no, but rather by grepping my entire filesystem for DHCP settings: `grep -ri 'dhcp' /`. There's almost certainly a better way. But anyways:

Earlier attempts at playing around with ISCSI netbooting on this machine somehow led to the creation of a **`/run/network/dynamic-interfaces`** file, which appears to use the same syntax as `/etc/network/interfaces`. Sure enough, therein was the line telling the machine to bring up eth0 as DHCP, and since this is happening in the context of `initramfs`, it's bringing the interface online long before `iftools` gets a chance.

This file is part of the `cloud-initramfs-dyn-netconf` package which is standard on Ubuntu server. You don't want to uninstall it since it's part of the `ubuntu-server` metapackage (and if you uninstall that, upgrades might fail in the future)

After clearing the file and rebooting, the NIC is controlled by the `interfaces` file as normally expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct wording is *static*; not manual. As well, have you determined that the address you have selected, 192.168.88.50, is outside of the range of addresses used for DHCP in the router so as to avoid a collision? Perhaps x.50 is already in use or reserved.

After determining the DHCP pool in the router, I suggest that you amend the file to:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.88.zz
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.88.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.88.1
dns-domain mynet.lan
```

...where zz is an address outside of the DHCP pool.

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

The -v for verbose should produce output that tells us if the connection was successful.

Did you get the requested address?

```
ifconfig
```

Comment: This did not work - the interface still broadcasts for DHCP upon being brought up.

Comment: Any clues in the log? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i -e eth -e dhcp` As the result is probably lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: My last comment was slightly in error - no DHCP broadcast, rather it was holding an old address

After downing the interface, `ip addr` still shows the erroneous .222 address. I issued an `ip address flush eth0`, but more likely than not it's still going to come back on reboot. Whatever's happening is only happening on bootup. Question updated with this new info.

There are no dhcp lines in syslog, just the "Ip-Config:" line that's only visible *at startup*, not in my log files, dmesg, or journalctl..

Comment: Could it be your BIOS looking for PXE DHCP? Have you ever used PXE to network boot the machine? I admit that it seems unlikely but it's something I can think of that wouldn't show up in log files. Maybe it's erroneously taking an address that isn't coming back with option 60 set after the boot process has begun? Have you tried running wireshark/tcpdump while it boots to look at the DHCP request?